# Positioning ZedGraph legend at middle right not top right?

Tags: graph, zedgraph

Is there some way to position the legend using ZedGraph so that it is on the right-hand side, but vertically centred.  Using:

```
output.Legend.Position = ZedGraph.LegendPos.Right
```

positions the legend at the top right, but beside a pie chart this looks misaligned.  Is there a way to get the legend to vertically centre?
Changing `output.Legend.Location.Y` seems to have no effect, nor does trying `output.Legend.Location.AlignV = ZedGraph.AlignV.Center`

Added in response to first answer below...

Floating, reducing the chart size and positioning the label does centre vertically, and is better than I had managed previously.  Unfortunately it has a side-effect, in that the legend switches to multi-column and tries to occupy half the width of the total chart area, thus usually overlapping the chart (see picture).  Looking at the ZedGraph source, this wider mode is used for all layouts except Left and Right.

[image: Multi-column legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Location` is only enabled when `Legend.Position` is set to `Float`.

You could do like this (C#):

```
output.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float;
output.Legend.Location = 
   new Location(1.05f, 0.5f, CoordType.ChartFraction, AlignH.Right, AlignV.Center);
```

with the probably undesired "feature" that the legend is drawn partially inside the chart:

[image: Legend in chart]

To workaround this issue I believe you also have to manually resize your chart:

```
output.Chart.Rect = new RectangleF(xstart, ystart, xsize, ysize);
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer, although there is a side-effect in that the legend becomes very wide once floated - so either overlaps the chart, or the chart has to be very small.  I've updated the question with a picture.  I've accepted this answer as it has led me to my eventual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Anders' answer nearly worked, except it had the side-effect of changing the width of the legend.  This led me to download the source code to find out why, and I discovered that the legend positioning code is actually quite trivial.  `LegendPos.Right` is only referenced twice in the code, both times in `Legend.CalcRect`
Adding a new `LegendPos.MiddleRight` only needs it added to the enum, a case for `MiddleRight` added to the first Switch which runs the same code as `Right`.  And in the second Switch in `CalcRect` the following:

```
    case LegendPos.MiddleRight:
        newRect.X = clientRect.Right - totLegWidth;
        newRect.Y = tChartRect.Top + tChartRect.Height / 2 - totLegHeight / 2;
        tChartRect.Width -= totLegWidth + gapPix;
        break;
```

This is the same code as for `LegendPos.Right` except for the newRect.Y line.

Comment: Stuart, great work! I definitely think you should provide this patch to the [Zedgraph  project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/), I am sure it would be useful for others as well.